# Issue with boolean on shared preferences

Tags: android, boolean, sharedpreferences

I am currently trying to start a service based on the boolean false or true when the phone boots up. The issue is if i use getBoolean

```
 boolean isPhysicalSirenFlagged = sp.getBoolean("isPhysicalSirenFlagged", true);
 boolean isSMSSirenFlagged = sp.getBoolean("isSMSSirenFlagged", true);
```

Both of them will get set to true whenever the phone boots up causing my both my isPhysicalSirenFlagged & isSMSSirenFlagged to be true when. Is it possible to check what is the current boolean of a value?

Code:

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
     String value = sp.getString("serial", "");
     boolean isPhysicalSirenFlagged = sp.getBoolean("isPhysicalSirenFlagged", true);
     boolean isSMSSirenFlagged = sp.getBoolean("isSMSSirenFlagged", true);

     if (isPhysicalSirenFlagged) {
         //true
         Intent physicaldialog = new Intent(context, PhysicalTheftDialog.class);
         physicaldialog.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
         context.startActivity(physicaldialog);
         context.startService(new Intent(context, PhysicalTheftService.class));
     }
     else {
         //false
     }

     if (isSMSSirenFlagged) {
         //true
         Intent smsdialog = new Intent(context, SMSNotificationPasswordDialog.class);
         smsdialog.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
         context.startActivity(smsdialog);
         context.startService(new Intent(context, RemoteSirenService.class));
     }
     else {
         //false
     }
```

Comment: I don't understand your problem.
If you set them to false, they will be false.

Comment: yes that's why i want to know instead of setting them to false is there a way to just check the current boolean of perhaps isSMSSIrenFlagged? Because both of the getBoolean statement will be executed no matter what when the phone boots up

Comment: @dythe No*. That is why there is a default value (the true that you are passing in as the second parameter).

Comment: I could not understand your question. You are trying to start the service when phone boots up. So, you can do without any boolean when your phone boots. Else if you have provided any setting in your app then work as per value. What is the issue in this? Note: To check default value in `sharedpreference`, a default value is passed which you are already passing `true`.

Comment: I'm sorry. I still don't understand your issue.. maybe the answers provided below could help.. if not, try to explain better. what is isSMSSirenFlagged? who sets it to what? since you're passing a default value of 'true' if isSMSSirenFlagged doesn't exists in the shared preferences, it would be marked as true...

Comment: @Lablabla I think this is OP's attempt at a phone boot up TheftPrevention service. The flags inform him what state the phone is in.

Comment: yup Aedon understood but i managed to get it working by using getString instead of getBoolean i could just use getString("isPhysicalSirenFlagged", ""); to get the current value and use if (isPhysicalSirenFlagged.equals("true") to do something

Comment: I understood what he was trying to accomplish. I just didn't understand what's the problem. if he can get a string saying true or false from SP, he can get the boolean because that means there's something in the SP. But as long as he got this working, good luck

Answer (score 1):

Have it set to false instead, obviously what ever you are doing is not commiting a change to the SharedPrefereces to indicate the flag. By using false as a default, you will prevent the accidental true assignment to the flags. Truthfully, you should be using int flags (or preferred an enum) to represent this. It is a much safer way of determining the state the device is in. for example:

```
int NO_STATE    = 0
int IS_THEFTED  = 1
int IS_WAILING  = 2

or

enum State {
    NONE, THEFTED, WAILING;
}
```

Comment: agreed, try: sp.getBoolean('key', false);