# Android issue with boolean on shared preferences

Tags: android, boolean, sharedpreferences

Android issue with boolean on shared preferences

```
SharedPreferences spref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
boolean isSlide=spref.getBoolean("SLIDE_SHOW",false);   

//in isSlide am getting the right value but the if statement is not working

if(isSlide==true){
//if true the page will slide but it works in false too
}
```

i tried in this link [Issue with boolean on shared preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11848813/issue-with-boolean-on-shared-preferences) but the answer is not clear

settings code:

```
  <PreferenceCategory android:title="Slide Show" >
       <CheckBoxPreference android:title="Slide Show" android:key="SLIDE_SHOW" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
```

Comment: instead of if(isSlide==true) just have if(isSlide) May that help

Comment: I tried this too but its not working.

Comment: wen u setting that to true..post ur full code..

Comment: In app settings screen by using checkbox preference

Comment: 1) Your code is correct and should work, is there any exception in log?
2) The answer of your link sayed that is safer to use int flag instead of boolean. So try to Store int value instead of boolean (0 represent false and 1 represent true)

Comment: I think you haven't setted yet your SharedPreferences parameter so when you try to get his value he will always return the default value (*false* in your case)

Comment: Preference returns the correct value, but the if statement is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry i will not post the question correctly

The problem is not with preference it returns correct value the problem is in handler which is used to slide the viewpager based on the value which is returned by preference

the handler is running even though the activity is killed below the code solved my problem

```
SharedPreferences spref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
boolean isSlide=spref.getBoolean("SLIDE_SHOW",false);   

if(isSlide==true)
{
SlideShowTimer();
}



 public void SlideShowTimer()
 {
                    mFilterTask = new Runnable() {
                         @Override
                         public void run() {
                             int i=0;
                             itemPosition = viewPager.getCurrentItem() + 1;
                            if(itemPosition!=10)
                            {
                                  if(i <= adapter.getCount()-1)
                                    {
                                     viewPager.setCurrentItem(itemPosition,true);
                                     mHandler.postDelayed(mFilterTask, 3000);
                                        i++;
                                    }                               
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                //ViewPagerAdapter.mediaPlayer.stop();      
                                ViewPagerActivity.this.finish();
                            }    

                         }
                    };
                    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mFilterTask);                          
                    mHandler.postDelayed(mFilterTask,3000);
                }
               @Override
                  public void onDestroy(){
                       super.onDestroy();
                       mHandler.removeCallbacks(mFilterTask);
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check if your SharedPreference variables are active. This is an example on how to set the SharedPreference.

To write into SharedPreference:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("myPref", 0); 
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putBoolean("myBool", true);
editor.commit();
```

To read from SharedPreference:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("myPref", 0); 
if (prefs.getBoolean("myBool", false)) { //myBool is true; }
```